# Destinations chaining in Android Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have a simple navigation graph like this:

```
MainFragment -> ListFragment -> DetailFragment
```

How can I achieve a "shortcut" from MainFragment to DetailFragment, so that:

- UP navigation from DetailFragment will navigate to ListFragment within the graph and
- BACK navigation from DetailFragment will return to MainFragment (optionally, BACK could behave as UP)

Is this possible? Thanks for suggestions!

**EDIT:** My Solution

I can simply navigate to ListFragment first and then immediately to DetailFragment like this (I call both "navigate" calls from MainFragment):

```
findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.toListFragment())
findNavController().navigate(ListFragmentDirections.toDetailFragment(data))
```

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/#upback), which says, that "... Up button should function identically to the system Back button", I decided not to make differences between BACK and UP actions.

Answer (score 1):

To move through fragments using the navigation components you should link them in the navigation graph, go to `app-> res-> navigation-> graphName.xml`
(In the picture I use placeholders, use your fragments instead).
[image]

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) to navigate from one fragment to another you need to use this line `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.viewTransactionsAction);` 
Where `viewTransactionsAction` should be the id of the arrow (in the graph) from one fragment to the next.

[image]

To override the back button action use:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp();
}
```

And replace inside the navigation `nav_host_fragment` to the arrow id of the page you want to navigate to.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I figured out that I can simply call `navigate` multiple times from MainFragment, so I navigate from MainFragment to detail like this: `findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.toListFragment())` and immediately  `findNavController().navigate(ListFragmentDirections.toDetailFragment(data))`. :-) Also I found in [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/#upback), that "Up button should function identically to the system Back button" so I decided not to make diffecences between Back and Up. :-)

Comment: Would it be fine if publish this as another answer?